# Reverse a list to a range

Tags: python-3.5

I want to reverse a list to a specific range but I am new to Python and I am doing this. Actually i want to reverse a list but to a specific value and I am trying this.

```
>>> li = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> li = list(reversed(li))
>>> print (li)
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> for i in li(range(0,4,1))
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> for i in li(range(0,4,1)):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Improved formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What output are you trying to get?

If you want the certain parts of the list `li[2:]` will return `[4, 3, 2, 1]`
and `li[:3]` will return `[6, 5, 4]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use slicing and split the list into two for this.

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
final_list = li[:li.index(3)]
final_list = final_list.reverse() + li[li.index(3):]
```